# BASH Script to Create Libreoffice Database file that connects to existing spreadsheet 'database'

Tags: database, bash, libreoffice, mailmerge

I use Linux Mint and am mail merging labels in Libreoffice.

My mail merge data is in a spreadsheet.

An obstacle to migrating from MS Office (for me) was understanding that, when mail merging, Libreoffice writer imports database tables not spreadsheets.

So to make this easy, and remove this obstacle, a script placed in the same directory as the (single table) spreadsheet, worksheet=sheet1, that connects to the spreadsheet and creates the Libreoffice database file, would be really helpful.

I don't know how to do it, though for someone else it may be an 'off the top of the head' job.

The script needs to : Open Libreoffice, then connect to the spreadsheets worksheet, sheet1, then save itself as the same name as the spreadsheet, in the same directory, with same file name and the database file extension.

Such a script would significantly reduce the 'overhead' of mail merging using libreoffice.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a database file as data source for mail merging. In the mail merge wizard's third step, when selecting the "address list", just add the ods file as data source. Here's the dialogue after selecting the ods File `Untitled 1.ods` as data source in the mail merge wizard using the <kbd>Add...</kbd> button.

[image]

By default, the mail merge wizard offers the datasources that are already registered (Menu `View` -> `Data sources` or <kbd>F4</kbd>). You can't add a spreadsheet directly to the datasources (right-click in the data sources window -> `Registered databases` -> `New...`). But if you select a ods spreadsheet using the mail merge wizard, it will appear among the data sources.

Comment: Hi @tohuwawohu the scripting steps I'm after broadly perform the steps U outline above, LibreOffice will then already be aware of the spreadsheet database and ready for the mailmerge functionality to be used!  Thank you :)

Comment: Hmm - i really don't understand. There's simply no difference between selecting an odb file or an ods file as datasource in the mail merge. After selecting them, both stay available among the data sources. BTW: I assume you can't use a bash script to automate some actions inside LO. You would have to combine it with a StarBasic macro, and that simply doesn't make sense in this simple case...